# Recommendation for blockchain network selection

Tags: private-blockchain, ethereumjs, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain-as-a-service

Is it a good idea to use fabric for one network, one organization (with multiple users), and storing transactions between those? or should I use a simpler blockchain network? I want the transaction to be private between the users themselves?

Comment: First I'd evaluate the use case, a blockchain network may not be the best solution.
That being said, if you are looking for private transactions you have a few options

Use a public network and obfuscate data:
(IE: you can store just a hash, and keep the data off-chain, or use a ZKP based solution) AFAIK, this is technically not GDPR compliant if the data contains PII (Which is really dumb)

Use a permissioned network:
Fabric, Besu, or Corda are the biggest ones.
Besu with the EEA privacy module is by far the easiest to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will look into Besu with EEA privacy module. I have another question can I use ERC20 token with it as well. The transaction I'll be doing will be token transaction in which erc20 tokens will be passed on between the users. I saw there is erc20 token in fabric but I can't find it in besu. @EnriqueAlcázarGarzás

Comment: You can only build proper ERC20s in EVM based blockchains.
Which means that you can create an ERC20 in Besu take that same code to Ethereum mainnet, Polygon, Binance etc. and it will work the exact same way.
With Fabric you can't, you can only create ERC20like contracts but they won't work in other networks, there are some plugins that may help, but it's not native like Besu

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try Hyperledger BESU for starters.